# Which airplane of the KLM flew from PBM to AMS on January 19th 1991?

Tags: air-travel, ams, history, klm, pbm

For quite some time I log the planes I travel on. I would very much like to log planes I took before I start logging plane registration numbers.

Is there any way to know which Boeing 747-300 I traveled on on January 19th 1991 from Paramaribo (Suriname) to Amsterdam (the Netherlands).

Comment: This won't help you but maybe someone else will find this useful. The US Bureau of Statistics publishes a complete list of flights from or to the US from 1990 onwards: http://www.transtats.bts.gov/Tables.asp?DB_ID=111&DB_Name=Air%20Carrier%20Statistics%20%28Form%2041%20Traffic%29-%20All%20Carriers&DB_Short_Name=Air%20Carriers

Comment: I tried to check pictures on airliners.net if you got chance.. but no results for january

Comment: Might be worth asking their twitter account - they'd probably appreciate something fun to investigate instead of the complaints their team might have to deal with (as many social media reps for companies have to, not singling them out or anything).

Comment: any chance you have the flight number?

Comment: And which Paramaribo airport - PRM or ORG?

Comment: @markmayo Why didn't I think of that: https://twitter.com/andrawaag/status/499153862662836225

Comment: Here's hoping for a reply!

Comment: Might also hop into the aviation.SE chat and see if they can suggest any sites that might have recorded it

Comment: @markmayo Klm didn't know the answer: https://twitter.com/andrawaag/status/499153862662836225

Answer (score 3):

It may be next to impossible to find the flight plan and the aircraft registration for that date.

However, there is a limited number of aircraft that it could be since [KLM operated only 3 747-300s](http://www.airfleets.net/flottecie/KLM-history-b747.htm).  The list is:

- [N4548M](http://www.airfleets.net/ficheapp/plane-b747-23056.htm)
- [PH-BUW](http://www.airfleets.net/ficheapp/plane-b747-23508.htm)
- [N4551N](http://www.airfleets.net/ficheapp/plane-b747-23137.htm)

Comment: I believe KLM also had some converted 200->300 ones

Comment: That was an upgrade for the 200 model but not a conversion of the model.

Comment: From the flights people recorded about these planes, I believe it is likely the first, named PH-BUU at that time (http://www.airfleets.net/flightlog/index.php?file=result&app=b747&msn=23056). The others apparently were likely used to fly to Canada at the beginning of the 90s.

Comment: @Vince There is no reason to assume that was the case.  The scheduling of the airplanes may change due to maintenance, unforseen issues and just because.